# Are there 'startscroll' and 'stopscroll' events in JS or JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, dom-events, javascript-framework

I'm looking for a 'startscroll' and 'stopscroll' events for a tracking when an user start and stop using scroll of window. Are there events in pure JavaScript or jQuery framework?

Answer (score 1):

There is `window.onscroll`, and a [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) to wrap it.

Comment: window.onscroll method issues events on each changing of scroll but I need to listening for start and stop only.

Comment: No such thing for non-touch browsers. You can hack something together by checking scrollTop / scrollLeft or onmousewheel...

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that hack